# Mixin for a JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to create a mixin for a `jQuery` selector (please note, I don't need no plugins, they are just too bulky for what I'm doing)?

Here's the task I'm trying to accomplish:

```
  // Given a div I need to paint it with green for which...
  var $container = $("#id001");

  // current solution
  var do = function(e) {

     var container = e.container;
     container.css("backgroudColor", "green");
  };

  do({ container: $container }); // call


  // desired solution
  var do**Mixin** = function(e){
     e.css("backgroudColor", "green");
  };

  container.do(); // call
```

Comment: @Neal - You really want the OP to fully describe an OO concept in a question?!? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Comment: A mixin is a pure magic, which allows for using a strange function as if it'd be part of the object itself.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what jQuery plugins are for? How are they too bulky? Just define `$.fn.do()` and it should work as you want. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @Jamiec: I've been using JavaScript/jQuery for years, and I've never heard the term "mixin".

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Thats because its not specifically to do with js/jQuery. My point was though, if you dont understand a term, surely you just go read wiki, not ask the OP to fully explain a term

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said you don't need a plugin, but a plugin for what you need is very simple:

```
function($){
    $.fn.makeItGreen = function(){
        return this.each(function() {
            this.css({
                'background-color': 'green'
            });
        });
    }
)(jQuery));
```

Use:

```
$(yourSelector).makeItGreen();
```

Untested, but....pretty sure it should work as is.

**Fiddle** (courtesy of Jamiec):

http://jsfiddle.net/mPu6X/

Comment: There's a few things wrong with this. 1) You dont need `$(this)` inside the plugin, 2)you should return `this.each(...)` from a plugin

Comment: Edited. wrote it off the top of my head. Figures i missed something or other ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom event:

```
$('selector').on('changeToGreen', function(){
    $(this).css("backgroudColor", "green");
});
```

To "do" it:

```
$('selector').trigger('changeToGreen');
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WDmjS/

```
​jQuery.prototype.do = function(){
    this.css("background-color","green");
    return this;
};

$(".mydiv").do();
```

​More concisely written:

```
​$.fn.do = function(){
    return this.css("background-color","green");
};
```

Comment: While `jQuery.prototype.do` is correct, you usually do `$.fn.do`.

Comment: Also, OP requested `return this.parent().css("background-color","green");` but I'm nitpicking. This is great.

Comment: @ChrisLike I don't believe he is.

Comment: @Shmiddty seemed to me that: `var container = e.container;` was a mysterious reference to a parent element. I'm probably just projecting.

Comment: @ChrisLike Yeah, why the OP didn't just pass in `$container` instead of enclosing it in an object is beyond me.